# How to Split a URL and Store into different strings

Tags: c#, split

I want to split my URL like if there is `ftp.akshay.com/a/b/c` then i want to **split it** into `ftp.akshay.com` and `/a/b/c` but there is one catch **sometimes it will be a unc file path** like **`Y:\A\B\C or U:\A\B\C`** that time i want to **split it into `Y:` and `\A\B\C`** How do i split the string. I thought of splitting with / but that's not useful. I want to use C# for this.

Comment: use `Uri` class

Comment: And `Path` static class for the second case. How come you found nothing after googling?

Comment: Yes but how do i find if its uri or unc?

Comment: Load into a URI and use the "IsUnc" or "LocalPath" properties. "LocalPath" will be blank if its "ftp://" style I believe and "IsUnc" will be true for "\\server" style I believe.

Answer (score 0):

please Try this

```
 string[] result = test.Split(new string[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
 string s1 = result[0];
 string s2 = "";
 for (int i = 1; i < result.Length; i++)
 {
     s2 = s2 + result[i].ToString() + ((i == (result.Length - 1)) ? "" : "/");
 }
```

Comment: what happens if its .com, .family? What if its \\server\folder1? Your solution isn't particularly scaleable.

Answer (score 0):

If you would not like to use `URI` and create logic behind it, you can split the url manually using regex to match specific pattern and split based from the index of the matched pattern.

```
private string[] splitUrl(string url)
{
    Match match = Regex.Match(url, @"\:|\.(.{2,3}(?=/))"); // Regex Pattern
    if (match.Success)  // check if it has a valid match
    {
        string split = match.Groups[0].Value; // get the matched text
        int index = url.IndexOf(split);
        return new string[] 
        { 
            url.Substring(0, index + split.Length),
            url.Substring(index + (split.Length), url.Length - (index + split.Length))
        };
    }

    return null;
}
```

and this is how you call the function,

```
string[] urls = splitUrl(@"ftp.akshay.com/a/b/c");
```

this will not be the perfect solution but it will give you atleast your starting point.

This pattern - `\:|\.(.{2,3}(?=/))` means match `:` or `.` with 2-3 strings and before `/`.

Comment: This works exactly how I want but there can be urls like "ftp.akshay.com:8080/a/b/c" that time it fails to separate "ftp.akshay.com:8080" and "/a/b/c" It separates "ftp.akshay.com" and "8080/a/b/c"

Comment: @AkshayBheda try to change the pattern from `\:|\.(.{2,3}(?=/))` to `\:(?=\\)|\.(.+?(?=/))` and try to test again..

Comment: Can you show some screenshot that this pattern `\:(?=\\)|\.(.+?(?=/))` does not work?

Comment: Maybe you have to list all possible format then we can check from there. You did not mention that `Y:test/akshay/a/b/c` is valid.

Comment: The mentioned strings are all the requirements. I can use both the patterns in combination but i need to use only one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163840/discussion-between-akshay-bheda-and-john-woo).